# Class 'Illuminate\Http\Response' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

My app's backend suddenly stopped working, returning 500 HTTP error and this error in laravel.log:

```
[2020-09-16 12:28:15] local.ERROR: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Http\Response' not found in /home/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php:424
[2020-09-16 12:28:19] local.ERROR: Class 'Illuminate\Http\Response' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Illuminate\\Http\\Response' not found at /home/../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:751)
```

Laravel version is 5.8.37

Anyone knows what could be wrong?

I've tried chmod -R 777 storage/, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan config:clear and composer dump-autoload, none worked.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Removing the vendor folder and running the below command fixed the issue, however I've noticed some errors during composer dump-autoload.

```
composer install
```

Here are the errors that showed up:

```
Deprecation Notice: Class Twilio\TwiML\Voice\Echo_ located in ./vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/TwiML/Voice/Echo.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class ConsoleTVs\Support\Traits\StringFUnctions located in ./vendor/consoletvs/support/Traits/StringFunctions.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class App\Http\Controllers\BonusCardController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/BonusCardController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class App\UserPartner located in ./app/Models/UserPartner.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class App\UserMarathon located in ./app/Models/UserMarathon.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you pls show a piece of code is exactly causing this error?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't changed anything in my controllers, and the error log shows that the problem is in /vendor/, not in my controllers. Any idea what happened?

Comment: can you pls run composer dump-autoload, or may be this could be old error

Comment: @MuhammadTariq they said they already ran that

Comment: its strange btw, not exactly sure then

Comment: Really strange and I have no idea what to do, I'm losing a lot of users in my app because of that :(

Comment: You can remove vendor folder and run `composer install`. May be it will be work.

Comment: Running composer install again solved the problem! Thank you very much! However I've noticed some warnings during composer dump-autoload.

Comment: @AlexShd they are not "errors" they are notices ... the ones that reference files in your application you can change yourself, you are not following PSR4 standard, you can look into that to understand why ... the ones that reference things that are not in your application would be the responsibility of the package maintainers to update accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like somthing wrong with your `vendor` folder so remove old `vendor` folder then

run this cmd
`composer install` then `composer dump-autoload`

here `composer install` will install all the dependency of your project
and `composer dump-autoload` will load all the file which is necessary to work with those dependency

Comment: `composer install` will dump the autoload

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! I have posted some errors that showed up during composer dump-autoload, any idea what can I do to solve those?